# Awk summation is carried out without floating point precision

Tags: bash, awk, sum

I have a **file.txt** and I'm trying to summarize the values of the fourth and fifth columns:

```
^20170821^3007030^153^863.53^0.42^
^20170821^1402675^110^581.36^0.37^
^20170821^1404785^24^155.29^0.29^
^20170821^1406505^40^210.51^0.00^
^20170821^1005^1^18.00^0.00^
^20170821^9657^7^7.28^0.00^
^20170821^143646^86^486.59^0.08^
^20170821^342657^3^12.60^0.00^
^20170821^1006^4^7.04^0.04^
^20170821^1004^1215^3502.44^12.09^
^20170821^1007^932^6689.64^15.07^
^20170821^378228^1^2.80^0.00^
^20170821^704797^4^23.80^0.00^
^20170821^705642^2^9.80^0.00^
^20170821^703689^7^40.60^0.00^
^20170821^148340^75^382.81^0.20^
^20170821^257^2^5.60^0.00^
^20170821^3702^1^2.80^0.00^
^20170821^3703^1^7.00^0.00^
^20170821^258^1^7.00^0.00^
^20170821^920299^11^60.20^0.00^
^20170821^210705^2^14.00^0.00^
^20170821^867693^12^65.88^0.08^
^20170821^2635085^6^33.60^0.00^
^20170821^13211^140^409.18^0.58^
^20170821^64^2^14.00^0.00^
^20170821^13214^234^1685.91^1.26^
^20170821^13212^2^34.90^0.00^
^20170821^13213^2^2.80^0.00^
^20170821^18385^8^7.28^0.00^


 $awk -F '^' '{sum += $5} END {print sum}' file.txt
```

I get the following result: **15344.2**

```
 $awk -F '^' '{sum += $6} END {print sum}' file.txt
```

I get the following result: **30.48**

Then I checked the result in the Excel. It turned out that the awk addition was wrong in the first addition. Missing **0.04**.

[image]

How to sum the column correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't leave the floating point precision by using `print` in `Awk`, when you can use `printf()` with format-modifiers. E.g. do the same with `printf` with 2 digit precision control as below

```
awk -F '^' '{ sum += $5 } END { printf "%0.2f",sum }' file
15344.24
```

from the [GNU Awk - Modifiers for `printf` Formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html) under section precision states,

> `.prec`
>
> A period followed by an integer constant specifies the precision to use when printing. The meaning of the precision varies by control letter:

---

As a side note you can use `print` statement with a special `awk` variable `OFMT` as specified below,

[GNU Awk - Controlling Numeric Output with `print`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/OFMT.html#OFMT)

> The predefined variable `OFMT` contains the format specification that `print` uses with `sprintf()` when it wants to convert a number to a string for printing. The default value of `OFMT` is `"%.6g"`. The way print prints numbers can be changed by supplying a different format specification for the value of `OFMT`

This way your example can be modified to define the `OFMT` in the `BEGIN` clause to print with two digit precision control, i.e.

```
awk -F '^' 'BEGIN { OFMT="%.2f" }{ sum += $5 } END { print sum }' file
15344.24
```

This option is available in all [`POSIX` compliant `Awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) versions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
awk -F '^' '{sum += $5} END {printf "%.2f\n", sum}' file.txt
```

`"%.2f"` will make sure it is rounded to 2 decimal places.